# I want to merge mail notification of two different forms in 1 mail on WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

Is it possible to receive notification from two different forms in one mail?

thank in advance

Let’s say,
One form has order details and another form has delivery and personal information
(Both are in different page)
I was asking if there was any way to receive the data collected from these forms at the same time in one complete mail because this would make it more convenient for me to organize the data even though they are from different forms.

Is it possible?

Comment: The short answer is yes, if you build it that way. The longer answer is that it depends on the specific form system you are using, and how the system should "know" that one form is related to another form.